# delete .git directory. locked and permission denied

Tags: git, bash, permissions, permission-denied

I have tmp .git files that I can't remove no matter what I try.

I've tried chmod and rm from terminal:

```
chmod a+wx zzz_delete/
seth-laptop:Lepton_Master Seth_Mac$ sudo rm -rf zzz_delete/
rm: zzz_delete//.git/objects/tmp_object_git2_a03228: Permission denied
```

I ran a bash script to force chmod:

```
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /zzz_delete/.git/objects/tmp_object_git2_a03228: Operation not permitted
```

I tried delete from a Windows Machine. `Permission Denied.`

How can I change permissions and remove this tricky folder?

Comment: Is that directory on a network fs? Also are are using cygwin?

Comment: have you tried `sudo chmod 755 -R zzz_delete/`?

Answer (score 0):

It exists a special *attribute* that do not allow even to root to delete the file.
Try to see if the *Immutable Bit* was set on the file with:

`lsattr /zzz_delete/.git/objects/tmp_object_git2_a03228`

If it answers with something like

`----i--------   tmp_object_git2_a03228`

gotcha! You have just to unset it before removing:

```
sudo chattr -i nomefile
```

[**What is the Immutable Bit**](http://www.linuxdoc.org/HOWTO/Security-HOWTO/file-security.html) :
The  immutable  bit  can  be  used to prevent accidentally
       deleting  or overwriting a file that must be protected. It
       also  prevents  someone  from  creating a hard link to the
       file.  See  the  chattr(1) man page for information on the
       immutable bit.